# How can I delete saved tags in Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-tags

When I put a tag on a post, Tumblr saves that tag. Meaning, when I start making a tag on a different post later, it lists suggestions for autofill from previous tags I’ve made which so far have all been saved. How do I make Tumblr stop doing this? I want to delete some of the tags which I think are already useless.

Answer (score 2):

For the tab suggestions you'll have to go back to previous posts and remove them manually. Once that's done you'll be able to get the autosuggestions to stop.

One way to check is to go to `yourtumblr.tumblr.com/tags/tagiwanttodelete` and make sure none are there.

However, popular tags used by other Tumblrs will still show up in the suggestions.

Comment: Is this true? Tumblr never suggested a tag that I didn't use before. Also, only some of my used tags are suggested, not all.

Comment: you have to start typing before they'll give you the tab suggestions, but yes, they'll show *some* tags that are popular/common, but they won't try to display everything via suggestion.

Comment: The URL has been changed to `yourtumblr.tumblr.com/tagged/tagiwanttodelete`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Tumblr app, type down the search you want and look on the top right corner of the screen. You'll see a setting button or one like that, click it and change *Save this search* so that it will not be a saved tag.

Answer (score 0):

Type in the Tag you want to delete. When it pops up, click it, then hit untrack.

Comment: I like the way you use the capital letters but could you make a bit more out of the answer you just gave?

Comment: The OP wants to know how they can remove suggested tags in the post editor, not how they can remove tags that they are tracking. The tag suggestion removal appears somewhat trickier than this.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the app just click on the tracked tag and it will either say track or tracking and if you click on that so it says track it will not be on your list of tracked tags. I don't know if this works on a computer or not hope this helped!

Comment: This is a duplicate of another answer